# Are the MCU Mandarin's ten rings different from the ones in the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

After watching *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*, I wondered what the Mandarin's rings were like in the comics, compared to the MCU versions.

I ended up finding that they seem quite different in both power(s) and size. In the comics, they seem like a "cheap" version of the Infinity Stones (literal rings), and in the MCU they look like artifacts that enhance your combat abilities (wristbands), closer to Mjølnir.

**My question is :** Was there any time in the comics where the rings were used the same way as in the MCU, or had the same size? If so is there a chance that the rings in the MCU will turn out similar to the ones in the comics?

As a side note, I know that the Mandarin in the comics knew about the (10) [powers](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mandarin%27s_Rings#The_Rings) of the rings, whereas the MCU one didn't (assuming they had this power), so it seems unlikely that Disney will go down this path, but I'm still wondering.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Jonathan Schwartz -- the producer on *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* -- the design of the Mandarin's rings was altered specifically for the MCU, mainly because the filmmakers thought the finger rings from the comics would look "a little goofy" in live-action.

> “You know, it may have been a little bit of that, but I think it may just be, there was a little bit of, we sort of felt like the finger rings were going to look a little goofy in practice. And a little bit of leaning into the genre elements. How do we make that come together?"
>
> <sub>[Shang-Chi Producer Confirms Avengers' Infinity Stones Influenced MCU's Ten Rings Design (Exclusive)](https://thedirect.com/article/shang-chi-avengers-infinity-stones-mcu-ten-rings-design-exclusive)</sub>

The revised design was inspired by the Hung Gar Iron Rings seen in the 1978 kung fu film, *[The 36th Chamber of Shaolin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_36th_Chamber_of_Shaolin)*.

> "And so, one day we were watching a movie in the writer’s room, me, Destin, and Dave, called The 36th Chamber of Shaolin , which starts with a kung fu training montage, using many weapons, one of which had these Hung Gar Iron Rings, which are a traditional Kung Fu weapon. You may remember them from Kung Fu Hustle, where they’re very prominent. Destin looked at those rings and said ‘we should just do that for the Rings.’ And he was 100% right, and it was unique and so cool, it just felt like sort of the right thing to snap the movie into focus."
>
> <sub>[Shang-Chi Producer Confirms Avengers' Infinity Stones Influenced MCU's Ten Rings Design (Exclusive)](https://thedirect.com/article/shang-chi-avengers-infinity-stones-mcu-ten-rings-design-exclusive)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for all those informations ! This makes a lot more sense now !

Comment: Looking forward to Shaolin shadow boxing, and the Wu-Tang sword style, having a big part in the next movie.